# Font issue in TextView

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I have a TextView which contains just one letter. The size of the text is calibrated so that the letter occupies entire TextView area. Now one of my users reported a problem that the letter does not fit properly into the TextView. From the attached screenshot I can see that she uses some kind of custom font on her Samsung S4 device. I am sure that's the problem. Here are some snapshots:

Custom font in a TextView over ImageView:

[image: Custom font example on TextView]

Custom font in the Status Bar:

[image: Custom font example in the Status Bar]

Distorted letter N in my TextView:

[image: Distorted N letter on TextView]

Is there any way to make a TextView use standard android font ignoring any custom fonts that users applies? How can I install custom fonts on the emulator or Sony phone (do not have Samsung) and replicate the behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** you can set custom fonts to your app. Make use TypeFace class.

1. Create a folder called fonts under assets folder and place all your fonts in it (Font format ttc or ttf. Folder name can be anything)
2. Within you onCreate method add the below code.

   ```
   TextView mytextview= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_id);

   // Loading Font Face. Replace with your font file name
   Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your_custom_font.ttf");

   // Applying font
   mytextview.setTypeface(tf);
   ```
3. Similar way you can have as many as TypeFace you require and also use the same TypeFace declared on as many as TextView you want.

This **tutorial** below very well explains your requirement and also provides **screenshot** for better assistance.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-using-external-fonts/

Also kindly note that TypeFace has a lot of other options that you can play around with. You can refer the android docs to get an idea about them.

I hope it helped you.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

My advise:

1. Create a subfolder in your asset folder called fonts.
2. Put there the fonts you want to use (for example ttc, or ttf) Set
   your TextView typeface. For example:

   yourTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/yourFont.ttc"));

I hope it helps!!